# jquery Hide and show elements with add remove class

Tags: jquery

Help guys,

i'm creating a jquery thing,

There is a group of parent checkbox, every checkbox has a child checkbox. the child checkbox was set to display:none.

When you click one parent checkbox it will show the child checkbox.

but if you click another parent checkbox, the other checkbox that is currently showing child it must hide again.

here if my code..

```
<ul id="testdrive">
  <li class=" parent-1" id="the_id_1">CBD
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="CBD" name="CBD">
    <ul style="display: none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="CBD-town-7" id="town-7">Town 7
        <label>Town 7
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 7" name="Town 7">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="CBD-town-8" id="town-8">Town 8
        <label>Town 8
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 8" name="Town 8">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-2" id="the_id_2">Din-Dins
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="Din-Dins" name="Din-Dins">
    <ul style="display: none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="Din-Dins-town-11" id="town-11">Town 11
        <label>Town 11
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 11" name="Town 11">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="Din-Dins-town-12" id="town-12">Town 12
        <label>Town 12
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 12" name="Town 12">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-3" id="the_id_3">East
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="East" name="East">
    <ul style="display: none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="East-town-3" id="town-3">Town 3
        <label>Town 3
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 3" name="Town 3">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="East-town-4" id="town-4">Town 4
        <label>Town 4
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 4" name="Town 4">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-4" id="the_id_4">North
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="North" name="North">
    <ul style="display:none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="North-suburb-1" id="suburb-1">Suburb 1
        <label>Suburb 1
          <input type="checkbox" value="Suburb 1" name="Suburb 1">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="North-suburb-2" id="suburb-2">Suburb 2
        <label>Suburb 2
          <input type="checkbox" value="Suburb 2" name="Suburb 2">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-5" id="the_id_5">Out of Town
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="Out of Town" name="Out of Town">
    <ul style="display:none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="Out of Town-town-10" id="town-10">Town 10
        <label>Town 10
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 10" name="Town 10">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="Out of Town-town-9" id="town-9">Town 9
        <label>Town 9
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 9" name="Town 9">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-6" id="the_id_6">South
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="South" name="South">
    <ul style="display:none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="South-town-1" id="town-1">Town 1
        <label>Town 1
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 1" name="Town 1">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="South-town-2" id="town-2">Town 2
        <label>Town 2
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 2" name="Town 2">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=" parent-7" id="the_id_7">West
    <input type="checkbox" class="events-category" id="" value="West" name="West">
    <ul style="display:none;" class="child-list">
      <li class="West-town-5" id="town-5">Town 5
        <label>Town 5
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 5" name="Town 5">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="West-town-6" id="town-6">Town 6
        <label>Town 6
          <input type="checkbox" value="Town 6" name="Town 6">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the jquery that i used:

```
var $selexcta = jQuery.noConflict();
$selexcta('.events-category').change( function(){
    console.log('showing sub categories');
    var c = this.checked;
    if( c ){
        $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').slideToggle('fast');
        $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').addClass("mm");
    }else{
        $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').slideToggle('fast');
        $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').removeClass("mm");
    }
});
```

Comment: so, what's your question ;)?

Comment: maybe you should also add your css, or at least, the classes `fast` and `mm`

Comment: My question how to do that. :)

Comment: so what's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need (when a .child-list opens, the other that are open will close):
**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hFFsk/)**

```
var $selexcta = jQuery.noConflict();
$selexcta('.events-category').change(function () {
console.log('showing sub categories');
var c = this;
if (c.checked) {
    $selexcta('.events-category').each(function() {
        if (this != c) {
            this.checked =false;
            $selexcta('.child-list li input').prop('checked',false);
            $selexcta('.child-list').removeClass("mm")
        }
    });
    $selexcta('.child-list').each(function () {
        if (this.style.display != 'none' && this != $selexcta(this).next('.child-list')) {
            $selexcta(this).slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
    $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').slideToggle('fast');
    $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').addClass("mm");
} else {
    $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').slideToggle('fast');
    $selexcta(this).next('.child-list').removeClass("mm");
}

});
```

Comment: wow that's working good, but can we also remove the. mm class if we click other parent checkbox and also uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: yes your correct @Sergio, but also can you help me to remove the 'mm' class and unchecked the checkbox

Comment: @Mel, was that what you wanted?

Comment: by the way @Sergio, I am having a problem I applied Uniform JS for the checkbox the jquery you did is not working...

Comment: here is the new code with jquery that im using right now by help of Sergio. the html was changed after applying the uniform.js

http://jsfiddle.net/hFFsk/1/

Comment: @Mel, you changed the html structure so jQuery could not find the elements anymore. Check this fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/xbjc9/